# Complex structure and antipode map on the space of measured geodesic laminations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

Fix a closed hyperbolic surface $S$, which represents a point in the Teichmüller space $\mathcal{T}$ of the underlying topological surface.

[Thurston's earthquake theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthquake_map) implies an identification between the tangent space to $\mathcal{T}$ at $S$ and the space $\mathcal{ML}(S)$
of measured geodesic laminations,
$$
T_S\mathcal{T}\cong\mathcal{ML}(S).
$$
Namely, each tangent vector is realized as the velocity vector of the left earthquake flow for a unique measured geodesic lamination.

The tangent space $T_S\mathcal{T}$ has a complex structure and a compatible symplectic form (Weil-Petterson), whereas $\mathcal{ML}(S)$ is merely a piecewise linear manifold. However, it is known that the symplectic form on $T_S\mathcal{T}$ can be interpreted as an generalized intersection pairing on $\mathcal{ML}(S)$. I would like to know

> **Question:** Can one describe the complex structure and/or the antipode map on $T_S\mathcal{T}$ in terms of $\mathcal{ML}(S)$?

Here the antipode map means the map $T_S\mathcal{T}\rightarrow T_S\mathcal{T}: v\mapsto -v$. For example, take a simple closed geodesic with positive weight as a measured lamination, then which lamination does the antipode map send it to?